# how to make ng-model in h2 tags work

Tags: angularjs

I have this text in a h2 tag. I have tried an input field as well. I cannot get this calculation to push to this ng-model. What is the best way to go about this? This score is being calculated inside the brackets, but I need it to work with ng-model. I know ng-models work on select, input, and text areas. Not sure how to solve this:

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="score.name1" value="1">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="score.name2" ng-value="2">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="score.name3" value="3">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
<h2 ng-model="score.total">Score:  {{ (score.name1 -- score.name2 -- score.name3 / 3 }} </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So what you want is to bind this `{{ (score.name -- score.name2 -- score.name3 -- score.name4 --score.name5 -- score.name6 -- score.name7 -- score.name8 -- score.name9 -- score.name10 -- score.name13)/ 8 }}` to the score.total ??

Comment: Please fix your code in question and provide minimal example on plunker or somewhere. There are multiple errors here - first you are writing some properties on score that don't exist (score.name, score.name4...) Next why do you set up model on h2? there is no point in doing that- just set up score.total to be a function that returns your calculation and display it with {{score.total()}} inside h2. Also setting value like that is bad you should have data model set up on controller and remove those values. If you want to use it in template use ng-init. Using radio buttons for here is really bad.

Comment: @Priz yes I want that to be the total that is binded. It calculates fine, just want that to push to a ng-model

Comment: @Vzupo we can help you faster if you can provide more code as **pegla** has mentioned like your `LoginController`

Comment: Ng model binds to inputs. You can set up a watcher on the 3 inputs that calculates each time one of them changes and then set a variable with that value in your controller and then display that value in your view instead of the calculation. Done.

Comment: why you want that , you can use ng-bind instead

Comment: would i bind the ng-model to it?

Comment: actually i need it to be ng-model

Comment: i will be pushing this data somewhere

Comment: ok the binding works--thanks @Dakota

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


  <input type="radio" ng-model="score.name1" ng-value="1"> Red
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="score.name2" ng-value="2">
    Green
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="score.name3" ng-value="3">
    Blue
  <br/>
   <h2 ng-model="score.total">{{(score.name1--score.name2--score.name3)/3}}</h2>


</div>
```

Comment: score.total doesn't really go to the ng-model